# How can I view the JSON array as a list in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I am rendering a queryset on views.py like this:

```
person = MyDict.objects.filter(search_description = name)
    return render(request,'myPage/find.html',{'person':person})
```

Its rendering like this:

```
person=[{     
   'gender': 'male',
   'description': ['24', 'Student', 'NY']
}]
```

If i apply the following code on my html:

```
{% for item in person %}
   {{ item.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

It returns as `['24', 'Student', 'NY']`
But I want to view as like this:

```
24
Student 
NY
```

How to do it???

Comment: Is `description` field of your model `JSONField`?

Comment: Yes its in my model...

Comment: Can you post your `MyDict` model?

Comment: You want print only description field in model or each field within loop?

Comment: @Jahongir Rahmonov 

gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description= models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender

Comment: @NafiPantha well, your `description` is not a list but a string. That's why you get this result.

Comment: Yes. Anyway can I convert them to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` template tag of django

```
{{ item.description|join:"<br>" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to make templatetags for check value type is list or not.

**templatetags code:**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def is_list_type(data):
    return isinstance(data, list)
```

**html code:**

```
{% load <templatetag file name> %}
{% for item in person %}
    {% is_list_type item as result %}
    {% if result %}
        {% for value in item %}
           {{value}} <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ item}}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Output:**

```
male
24
Student 
NY
```